# Execute function on local client PHP

Tags: php

On a users computer they can enter (192.168.1.100 is their local IP) this:

```
http://192.168.1.100:6333/api/call?type=1
```

straight into their search bar and it will execute a function on their machine, but I am trying to do this so they can make this same call straight through my website, but it does not seem to work, here is what I tried

```
$response = file_get_contents("http://192.168.1.100:6333/api/call?type=1");
```

I'd imagine this should work the same as if the user enter this URL straight into their search bar, but I am wrong it does not seem to work. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: from your website is 192.168.1.100 accessible, i mean on same network?? and if yes then is CORS allowed for any host on 192.168.1.100:6333/api/. this means cross origin. Your api must allow any origin. Last but not least is firewall allowed for inbound traffic on 192.168.1.100?

Comment: If you setup phpmysql xampp or wampp and save the code on client local machine you have to give ip of this machine or set as a localhost  this is when if you and your client not sharing same network

Comment: @webDev — It's PHP. CORS is irrelevent. There is no Same Origin Policy for CORS to relax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant just do that like that. That IP address is your local IP, the outside world will see another IP, the one for your modem/router setup. If you'll go to [a website that gives you your IP](https://www.whatismyip.com/), you'll get another IP.
The solution isn't as easy as replacing the IP in the callback, as your router/modem has a firewall to stop baddies from accessing your PC. In this case, it'll see you as a baddy.

There are some ways around it. You could setup a cheap host account somewhere and place the website there. You can now add a domainname and make things easier for your. This is by far the easiest long term option. A cheap hosting account doesn't cost much and will save you a lot of time. (besides, leaving your friends PC on will probs cost you more in electricity).

You can open a port in the router/modem you can can portforward the connection so your router knows which PC to call. I'm not skilled in this department so I can't tell you how, but there are tutorials. In my experience, this will not go easily when you don't know what you're doing.

You can make your friends PC connect to the outside world, either via polling with a AJAX script or a simple socket connection. This is a easy solution too, but the polling may take up a lot of bandwidth in the long run, if you have to pull often.